# SQL Server backup and restore from C# problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

I have written a program in C# to use SQL 2008.

I want to backup the database and restore it. My code for backup works correctly but restore doesn't work and the database becomes single user.

Get the following error :

> The tail of the log for the database
>   "doctor" has not been backed up. Use
>   BACKUP LOG WITH NORECOVERY to backup
>   the log if it contains work you do not
>   want to lose. Use the WITH REPLACE or
>   WITH STOPAT clause of the RESTORE
>   statement to just overwrite the
>   contents of the log. RESTORE DATABASE
>   is terminating abnormally.
>   Nonqualified transactions are being
>   rolled back. Estimated rollback

My code:

```
private void Backup(string strFileName)
{
    try
    {
        string command = @"BACKUP DATABASE doctor TO DISK='"+ strFileName+"'";
        SqlCommand oCommand = null;
        SqlConnection oConnection = null;
        oConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=doctor;Integrated Security=True");
        if (oConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        oConnection.Open();
        oCommand = new SqlCommand(command, oConnection);
        oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}   

private void Restore(string strFileName)
{
    try
    {
        string command = "ALTER DATABASE doctor SET SINGLE_USER with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE " + "use master " + " RESTORE DATABASE doctor FROM DISK='" + strFileName + "'";
        SqlCommand oCommand = null;
        SqlConnection oConnection = null;
        oConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=doctor;Integrated Security=True");
        if (oConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            oConnection.Open();
            oCommand = new SqlCommand(command, oConnection);
            oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();               
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you concat

> " WITH REPLACE "

with your restore string it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The error you've got is a `MSSQLSERVER_3159` error, the explanation and user action ca be found on

[msdn : MSSQLSERVER_3159 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283410.aspx)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your database is using full recovery mode, and under normal circumstances a log backup is required.

Depending on your scenario, Nima's answer may suffice.

See the following topics on MSND for more information on the topic:

- [Performing a complete database restore (Full recovery mode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187495.aspx)
- [Tail-log backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179314.aspx)